# using gifski to make gif out of pngs

Tags: r, gif

I am trying to make a gif out of 1,233 pngs.

I am trying:

```
png_files <- list.files("E:/S3_Backup_Anna/S3_L1/Subset_S3_L1/subset_pngs_rename", pattern = ".*png$")

gifski(png_files, gif_file = "subset_L1.gif",width = 800, height = 600, delay = 1)
```

I keep getting an error:

```
Frame 3 (0%)Failed to add frame 3
Frame 4 (0%)Error in gifski(png_files, gif_file = "subset_L1.gif", width = 800, height = 600,  : 
  Failure writing image E:\S3_Backup_Anna\S3_L1\Subset_S3_L1\subset_pngs_rename\subset_L1.gif
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try to make this [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), possibly with images that ship with a related package (don't actually know if that's a thing). Right now, best anybody could do is guess

Comment: I'm unable to upload the png files i'm working with but any png files could be used to test this code I think?

Comment: Hey Anna, it works for me.. with say 3 png files. Something wrong with one of your pngs? png_files[3] maybe?

Comment: For reference, i used: for(i in levels(iris$Species)){ png(paste0("iris.",i,".png")); plot(iris[,1:2],col=factor(iris$Species %in% i));dev.off()} ; png_files <- list.files(pattern="iris[^ ]*png$") ; gifski(png_files, gif_file = "iris.gif",width = 800, height = 600, delay = 1)

Comment: Not sure what's going on.. my PNGs are different sizes but I don't think that matters? I keep getting the "Failure writing image" error after everything I try. Is there another gif command I can try?

Comment: The PNGs must have the same size.